# Why my SVG image is not filling color?

Tags: css, image, svg

Hi there can someone please help me why the fill color it is not working with svg image ..

```
<img  class="svg" style="opacity: 0.5; fill: red !important;" src="{{ asset('icons/favorited.svg') }}" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change fill color using style if the svg is applied to `img` tag

You have 2 solutions:

1- Change it inside the svg file itself, this will work if it will always have a single color.

2- Use the svg directly as inline element in your html and then you can change the fill using css `fill:"#color"`